# HTTP client certificate var in nginx is blank?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, fingerprint

I am trying to get HTTP client certificate in nginx but the always return as blank.

- $ssl_client_cert
- $ssl_client_fingerprint
- $ssl_client_raw_cert
- $ssl_client_serial

All of the above return as blank.

```
server {
    listen   8014;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /root/cert/certificates/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /root/cert/certificates/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    location / {
    proxy_set_header ssl-hash $ssl_client_fingerprint;
    proxy_set_header ssl-cert $ssl_client_cert;
    proxy_set_header ssl-raw-cert $ssl_client_raw_cert;
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:3128;
}}
```

I tried to pass the variable to my go app but the header is blank.

```
server {
    listen       8014;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /root/cert/certificates/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /root/cert/certificates/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    location / {
            root        /opt/hthash;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
                autoindex on;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /opt/hthash;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_CERT       $ssl_client_cert;
        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_RAW_CERT   $ssl_client_raw_cert;
        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_FPRINT       $ssl_client_fingerprint;
        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_SERIAL     $ssl_client_serial;
        include        fastcgi_params;
}}
```

Also tried with fastcgi php but still no luck.

Can anybody tell me how get the HTTP client certificate preferably by the reverse proxy or any other solution?

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Without specifying [`ssl_verify_client`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client) anywhere, your server is not asking the client for a certificate. That means there is none.

You need to set it to either `on` (certificate required), `optional` (certificate requested but not required) or `optional_no_ca` (certificate requested, but not required; also not verified).

Comment: You made my day.